# не работает вывод даты и времени в таблицу

Tags: php, sql, datetime

Все данные выводятся в таблицу отлично, кроме даты. В базе данных тип поля DATETIME.

А когда я просто в коде вывожу эту переменную через echo, то она отображается отлично.

```
<body>  

 <?php  
$query = "SELECT * FROM `payeer_table` ORDER BY `date_time` DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$htmlToDisplay = ''; //this variable will contain table rows

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   
      $phpdate = strtotime( $row["date_time"] );
      $formated_date = date( 'd.m.Y H:i:s', $phpdate );      
                                      
    $htmlToDisplay .="<tr>
                         <td>".$row["login"]."</td>
                         <td>".$row["payeer"]."</td>
                         <td>".$row["money_income"]."</td>
                         <td".$formated_date."</td>
                      </tr>";  
  }
} else {
  $htmlToDisplay = "<tr><td>0 results</td><tr>";
}
?> 

<table class=" blueTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>login</th>
      <th>payeer</th>
      <th>money_income</th>
      <th>date_time</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <!-- echo your php row(s) here in a slightly neater way since it's one line -->
    
    <?php echo $htmlToDisplay; 
     echo $formated_date;

     ?> 
     
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
```

Comment: `<td".$formated_date."</td>` => `<td>".$formated_date."</td>`

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее за помощь. Не могли бы Вы объяснить почему так происходит и зачем передавать переменную в саму себя?

Comment: Ты просто блин тег  `<td>` не закрыл, какая переменная в саму себя.

Comment: => означает передать переменную. теперь понял! Еще раз огромнейшее спасибо за помощь балбесу!

Comment: @ВадимСоловьев в контексте моего комментария => означает "замените на"

Comment: И почему вопрос закрыт за дубликат, если, по сути, тут дебаг не поможет?

Comment: я не знаю как дебагом пользоваться. установлен эклипс